# python-tkinter how to get one more argument in OptionMenu-command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

how can I  get the value and placeholder in "optMenFunc" function from each iteration as value changes as I am working on below mentioned code, which has four classes, SampleApp, StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo. Page one has optionmenu with for loop. I am following the answer of this: [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

```
import tkinter as tk


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

        placeHolders = ['one', 'two']
        for placeHolder in placeHolders:

            self.options = tk.StringVar()
            self.options.set('select')
            self.menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.options, "miss", "mr", "mrs", command = self.optMenFunc)
            self.menu.pack()  

    def optMenFunc(self, value):
        print("i need to print here value with placeholder")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `lambda` similar to how you did in the other `commands`.

```
self.menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.options, "miss", "mr", "mrs", command=lambda v, ph=placeHolder: self.optMenFunc(v, ph))
```

and

```
def optMenFunc(self, value, placeholder):
    print(f"value:{value} and placeholder:{placeholder}")
```

Note:

A: `command=lambda v: self.optMenFunc(v, placeHolder)`

B: `command=lambda v, ph=placeHolder: self.optMenFunc(v, ph)`

You have to set the argument in the `lambda`, as (B) is. If you do it the (A) way, `placeHolder` will equal whatever it's **final** iteration value is, regardless of which `OptionMenu` you select from. By making it an argument of the `lambda` you are saving it's **current** iteration value to `ph`.